# Performing MANOVA on tidy data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, manova

I am trying to perform a MANOVA on a tidy dataframe that looks somewhat like the following. "id" refers to the participant number. The independent variables are "init_cont" (with values of I or K) and "family" (with values of C, S, or D), making for a 2x3 design. The column "qnumber" refers to the number of the question participants answer, with each participant answering 3 questions. "value" is each participant's response to a particular question.

```
id  init_cont  family  qnumber  value
1   I          C       1        3.5
1   I          C       2        2
1   I          C       3        4
2   K          C       1        2
2   K          C       2        5
2   K          C       3        3
3   K          S       1        4.5
3   K          S       2        5
3   K          S       3        3
4   K          D       1        1
4   K          D       2        7.5
4   K          D       3        3
```

What is the best way for me to perform a MANOVA on this data? I am interested in the interactions between the independent variables and how they impact the "value" for each of the 3 questions. In case it is relevant, my actual dataset has 14 different questions.

I have considered reorganizing the data in the following format, but I am unsure how to do this in R. The numbers after "value" in each new column are from "qnumber".

```
id  init_cont  family  value1  value2  value3
1   I          C       3.5     2       4
2   K          C       2       5       3
3   K          S       4.5     5       3
4   K          D       1       7.5     3
```

Comment: You've got 2 questions here. The first (how to best perform MANOVA) is better suited for cross validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com. I highly suggest you head over there and ask about MANOVA, you'll get great answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::spread` does the first part of your problem easily.

```
df %>% spread(qnumber, value)
#   id init_cont family   1   2 3
# 1  1         I      C 3.5 2.0 4
# 2  2         K      C 2.0 5.0 3
# 3  3         K      S 4.5 5.0 3
# 4  4         K      D 1.0 7.5 3
```

Here is the reproducible data.

```
t <- 'id  init_cont  family  qnumber  value
1   I          C       1        3.5
1   I          C       2        2
1   I          C       3        4
2   K          C       1        2
2   K          C       2        5
2   K          C       3        3
3   K          S       1        4.5
3   K          S       2        5
3   K          S       3        3
4   K          D       1        1
4   K          D       2        7.5
4   K          D       3        3'

df <- read.table(text = t, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Spread does not work. It does not create 1 row for each id # like you displayed here. This question outlines the trouble I'm having with "spread": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055417/combining-rows-by-index-in-r

Comment: @melbez, it works with the data set you gave, unless you did not include enough information for us to replicate your problem. Make sure that you have `ungroup()`ed every grouping you did prior to using `spread`.